# Invertase: Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) with iOS devices

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to use push notifications on iOS devices with react-native.

I'm using Invertase and I managed to make them work on Android.

The only things I'm doing are: 
ask for the permission with `messaging().requestPermission();` and registering a token with

```
firebase.messaging().getToken()
```

I can get a token on both devices. However when sending them with   `admin.messaging().sendToDevice`
does display the notification on Android but not on iOS although I don't get any error for both.

**What Am I missing? Is there something more to do to handle notifications on the iOS part? Do I have to use [zo0r/react-native-push-notification](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) or [wix/react-native-notifications](https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications)?**

Could you provide a push notification code example working on iOS with Invertase?

Comment: Have you setup the APNs config in the Firebase console?

Comment: yes I have set it up